# Adding a static library to a Visual Studio project template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, static-libraries

I want to create a VC++ project template with an included dependency in the form of a lib file(s). However, when I export it, it doesn't actually include the lib file (everything else seems to be fine though) despite me setting the "Included In Project" flag to True. Moreover, just for curiosity's sake, I tried doing the same with a dll - and it actually worked fine, even though I'd still prefer to use a static lib.

How can I export a project template with a static lib in it? Are there some settings I'm simply not aware of?

Comment: Always hard to answer an "it doesn't work" question without version info and repro steps.  Just be explicit about it, tell the linker to link the .lib file with Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies.  And you probably want to tell the compiler where the .h file is located, so C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories.  This is normally done with a project property sheet.

Comment: Already did set include and lib paths, as well as additional dependencies, before the original post. Am using VS version 15.9.11, even though I've got the same issue on a newer version as well, so I'm not sure if it matters.